# create trigger after delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

When a row is deleted from `titles_in_stock` table, I want to insert equivalent row in table named `titles_in_stock_out`.

I tried the following

```
create trigger titles_in_stock_out
   on titles_in_stock
   after delete as
   begin
      insert into titles_in_stock_out
      (cd_title, invenotry, cd_type)
      values
      (deleted.cd_title, deleted.invenotry, deleted.cd_type)
   end
```

but this gives following error when tried to execute above statement.

> Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Procedure titles_in_stock_out, Line 8
>   The name "deleted.cd_title" is not permitted in this context. Valid
>   expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some
>   contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Any Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. The `deleted` is virtual table which available in trigger, then you must refer it as table.

```
create trigger titles_in_stock_out
   on titles_in_stock
   after delete as
   begin
      insert into titles_in_stock_out
      (cd_title, invenotry, cd_type)
      select cd_title, invenotry, cd_type
      from deleted
   end
```

This will helpful in cases when you deleted more than one row.

Comment: tried it & get followin error Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure titles_in_stock_out, Line 5
There is already an object named 'titles_in_stock_out' in the database.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but get this error. Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure titles_in_stock_out, Line 5
There is already an object named 'titles_in_stock_out' in the database.

Comment: You have already the object by name `titles_in_stock_out` in your database. You can change the name of your trigger or if it is your trigger you can use `alter trigger` instead of `create trigger`.

Comment: @lalu You need another name for the trigger as you already have an object named `titles_in_stock_out`, see my answer for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to`deleted`as a table, and also the trigger needs to have a different name; in your example it had the same name as the table.

```
create trigger titles_in_stock_out_trig
   on titles_in_stock
   after delete as
   begin
      insert into titles_in_stock_out
      (cd_title, invenotry, cd_type)
      select 
      cd_title, invenotry, cd_type
      from deleted
   end
```

Comment: `titles_in_stock` not same as `titles_in_stock_out`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No, but it is the same as the destination table and you will get an object name conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
    create trigger titles_in_stock_out
       on titles_in_stock
       FOR  delete 
       begin
   insert into titles_in_stock_out
      (cd_title, invenotry, cd_type)
      select 
      cd_title, invenotry, cd_type
      from deleted
       end
```

Answer (score -1):

This should solve your problem :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('titles_in_stock_out', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
DROP TRIGGER titles_in_stock_out
GO
CREATE TRIGGER titles_in_stock_out
ON titles_in_stock
FOR DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO titles_in_stock_out
      (cd_title, invenotry, cd_type)
      VALUES
      (cd_title, invenotry, cd_type)
      SELECT 
      cd_title, invenotry, cd_type
      FROM titles_in_stock
END
```

Comment: You canot use the values clause and the select clause in the same insertn